# VLOOKUP Syntax for Conditional Formatting Rule

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, vlookup

I'm writing a conditional formatting rule that formats a cell if a VLOOKUP formula returns a value > 0.

I usually write out the formula in a cell first to ensure it is syntactically correct. In this case my formula looks like

```
=VLOOKUP(A116,Table5,2,FALSE)>0
```

This formula resolves to the expected value of TRUE.

I'm taking this formula and pasting it into a new conditional formatting rule.

[image]

Of note, Excel has added quotes around the formula (my suspicion is that this is the issue).

When I apply the rule, the formatting does not change. My guess is that I have a syntactical error in the formatting rule itself and that I need to add an additional condition when using this formula in the context of conditional formatting. What modifications do I need to make in order for this formatting rule to work as intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "issue" is the structured reference `Table5`.  Conditional Formatting does not like them.

One will need to use INDIRECT: `

```
=VLOOKUP(A116,INDIRECT("Table5"),2,FALSE)>0
```

Comment: This is a good use case for Indirect(). CF is volatile, anyway.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks much.